# Speed of Convergence to 5^(1/3).

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

The following methods compute $5^{1/3}$. Rank them in order, based on their apparent speed of convergence.

$
\begin{align*}
(1) \quad &p_{n}=p_{n-1}-\frac{p_{n-1}^{3}-5}{3p_{n-1}^{2}}\\\\
(2) \quad &p_{n}=\frac{4p_{n-1}+5/p_{n-1}^{2}}{5}\\\\
(3) \quad &p_{n}=p_{n-1}-\frac{p_{n-1}^{4}-5p_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}^{2}-5}\\\\
(4) \quad &p_{n}=\left(\frac{5}{p_{n-1}}\right)^{1/2}\\\\
\end{align*}
$

The definition for speed of convergence from Burden and Faires:

Suppose $\{p_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a sequence that converges to $p$, with $p_{n} \neq p$ for all $n$. If constants $\lambda, \alpha > 0$ exist with
    $$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|p_{n+1}-p|}{|p_{n}-p|^{\alpha}}=\lambda,
 $$
then $\{p_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ converges to $p$ of order $\alpha$, with asymptotic error constant $\lambda$.

How can I most efficiently use this definition to solve the above problem?

Comment: I almost feel like the word "apparent" here suggests that they merely want you to look at the first couple of terms of each of these sequences and then determine which one "seems" to converge to $\sqrt[3]5$ the fastest.

Comment: If $p_n\to p$ with convergence constants $\alpha$ and $\lambda$, and $p_n'\to p$ with convergence constants $\alpha'$ and $\lambda'$, what is the comparison of $(\alpha,\lambda)$ to $(\alpha',\lambda')$ that says which sequence converges faster?

Comment: Consider the functions corresponding to the iterations, for the first, take $$f(x) = x - \frac{x^3-5}{3x^2}.$$ All these functions are smooth (even real-analytic) in a neighbourhood of $5^{1/3}$, which is a fixed point. Use the Taylor expansion to find $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: @DanielFischer To make sure I'm on the right track, for the first function I got $\alpha=2$ and $\lambda=5^{-1/3}$. Do you agree?

Comment: Indeed I do. By the way, that is the Newton-Raphson method for finding the zero of $x^3-5$. If you don't already know that, read up on it, it's useful and important.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_n=\sqrt 5+\epsilon$ and evaluate $p_{n+1}$ to leading order in $\epsilon$.  For the fourth one, $p_{n+1}=\frac {\sqrt 5}{\sqrt{5+\epsilon}}=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+\frac \epsilon {\sqrt 5}}}\approx 1-\frac \epsilon{2 \sqrt 5}$ which tells you that the error is reduced by a constant factor each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Try this one !!!. Expand the binomial ( just a few terms ).

\begin{align}
5^{1/3} & = \pars{148955 \over 31^{3}}^{1/3} =
{1 \over 31}\pars{148877 + 78}^{\, 1/3} =
{53 \over 31}\pars{1 + {78 \over 148877}}^{1/3}
\end{align}

---

For instance, $\ds{{53 \over 31} \approx 1.709\color{#f00}{6\ldots}}$ and
$\ds{\pars{53 \over 31}^{3} = {148877 \over 29791} \approx 4.9974}$

Two terms: $\ds{{148903 \over 87079} \approx 1.7099759\color{#f00}{9\ldots}}$ and
$\ds{\pars{148903 \over 87079}^{3} = {3301492713910327 \over 660298482394039}\approx 5.000000\color{#f00}{4}}$